# Check health of RAID array

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have a server with RAID 1.

Currently when I type in the following command:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

I get:

```
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty] 
unused devices: <none>
```

What does this mean? The server works fine but why doesn't the RAID array show up here?

Comment: Are you talking about hardware raid or software raid? If Hardware: what kind of controller make and model? For example, for the MegaRaid series (including Dell PERC 6/7) you could use the MegaCLI tool from LSI to get the data. Hardware raid won't necessarily show up in /proc/mdstat

Answer (score 3):

This simply means you don't have any configured software raid device in your Linux box. I think you have a hardware raid controller which can not been seen this way.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially your mirror is based on LVM rather then the software raid driver or a hardware raid controller.

```
lvdisplay --maps
```

Comment: Not the case... "No volume groups found"